# adding segment to xml within the same xpath using xslt

Tags: xslt

I need to group some of the fields into a segment when the segment does not appear.

I am able to add the segment by checking if the segment already exists.

XML

```
<ns1:MT_SalesOrder xmlns:ns1="urn:salesorder">
    <Reason/>
    <OrderId/>
    <Invoice>
        <CreatedTimestamp>2019-07-24T14:37:29.573</CreatedTimestamp>
        <PublishCount>1</PublishCount>
        <Process/>
        <FailedAmount/>
        <InvoiceLine>
            <Address/>
            <Total>-270.0</Total>   
        </InvoiceLine>
    </Invoice>          
    <Info/>
    <Comments/>
    <Status/>
    <Taxes/>
    <Due>0.0</Due>
    <OrderTotal>5.0</OrderTotal>
    <messageKey>122345</messageKey>
    <message>99999</message>
    <errors>11111</errors>
    <exceptions>222222</exceptions>
</ns1:MT_SalesOrder>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="urn:salesorder">
   <ns0:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   <ns0:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <ns0:template match="node()|@*">
      <ns0:copy>
         <ns0:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </ns0:copy>
   </ns0:template>
   <ns0:template match="/ns1:MT_SalesOrder[not(data)]">
      <ns0:copy>
         <ns0:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <data>
            <ns0:apply-templates select="node()"/>
         </data>
      </ns0:copy>
   </ns0:template>
</ns0:stylesheet>
```

I am expecting the below structure, data to be added before messageKey Field.

```
<ns1:MT_SalesOrder xmlns:ns1="urn:salesorder">
    <data> <---------------------------------------------
    <Reason/>
    <OrderId/>
    <Invoice>
        <CreatedTimestamp>2019-07-24T14:37:29.573</CreatedTimestamp>
        <PublishCount>1</PublishCount>
        <Process/>
        <FailedAmount/>
        <InvoiceLine>
            <Address/>
            <Total>-270.0</Total>   
        </InvoiceLine>
    </Invoice>          
    <Info/>
    <Comments/>
    <Status/>
    <Taxes/>
    <Due>0.0</Due>
    <OrderTotal>5.0</OrderTotal>
    </data> <-------------------------------------------------
    <messageKey>122345</messageKey>
    <message>99999</message>
    <errors>11111</errors>
    <exceptions>222222</exceptions>
</ns1:MT_SalesOrder>
```

But I am getting the data segment added to the whole XML.

```
<ns1:MT_SalesOrder xmlns:ns1="urn:salesorder">
<data>
<Reason/>
<OrderId/>
<Invoice>
<CreatedTimestamp>2019-07-24T14:37:29.573</CreatedTimestamp>
<PublishCount>1</PublishCount>
<Process/>
<FailedAmount/>
<InvoiceLine>
<Address/>
<Total>-270.0</Total>
</InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
<Info/>
<Comments/>
<Status/>
<Taxes/>
<Due>0.0</Due>
<OrderTotal>5.0</OrderTotal>
<messageKey>122345</messageKey>
<message>99999</message>
<errors>11111</errors>
<exceptions>222222</exceptions>
</data>
</ns1:MT_SalesOrder>
```

I am not able to copy the part of the XML and group them, the field messageKey is the identifier to split the XML and add in data segment. Any leads will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You problem is a grouping problem: every element before `messageKey` should be into a new `data` element. There are many questions and answers about the topic in the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know in advance the names of all elements in the two groups, then the best way is to list them explicitly:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="urn:salesorder">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="ns1:MT_SalesOrder">
    <xsl:copy>
        <data>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Reason | OrderId | Invoice | Info | Comments | Status | Taxes | Due | OrderTotal"/>
        </data>
        <xsl:copy-of select="messageKey |  message |  errors |  exceptions"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Otherwise you can use `messageKey` as the "split point":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="urn:salesorder">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="ns1:MT_SalesOrder">
    <xsl:copy>
        <data>
            <xsl:copy-of select="messageKey/preceding-sibling::*"/>
        </data>
        <xsl:copy-of select="messageKey | messageKey/following-sibling::*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your suggestion. I did try this XSL, it adds data as a field before the messageKey. I want to add the data as a segment to include all the fields before messageKey.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. See the edited answer.

Comment: thanks michael. This works fine if the data segment is unavailable. I have to put in a check to do nothing, if the data segment already exists.